# Calling a method in main app from dll

Tags: delphi, dll

Can I call a method which is placed in main application from dll code?

Comment: See this example: [How to implement a callback method within DLL (Delphi / TJVPluginManager + TJvPlugin)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1839294/576719).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

seems there is only one way to do it - create a callback object.
in your application you have to declare interface, wich describes your method, for example:

```
IMyMethodInterface = interface(IInterface)
    procedure MyMethod(); stdcall;
end;
```

next you have to create class, wich implements this interface (and your method):

```
TMyMethodObject = class(TInterfacedObject, IMyMethodInterface)
  public
    procedure MyMethod(); stdcall;
end;
```

when you load DLL, you have to create `TMyMethodObject` instance and pass its `IMyMethodInterface` to dll; of course dll has to have corresponding method and export it (wich takes interface as parameter) `SetMethodCallback` wich stores interface reference:

vars:

```
var mmo : IMyMethodInterface;
    dllHandle : THandle;
    smc : procedure (mmi : IMyMethodInterface); stdcall;
```

code:

```
    mmo := TMyMethodObject.Create();

    dllHandle := LoadLibrary('mydll.dll');
    smc := GetProcAddress(dllHandle, 'SetMethodCallback');
    if assigned(smc) then
        smc(mmo);
```

now, you can use IMyMethodInterface reference in your dll to call method.

of course you can statically link dll and use it directly:

```
procedure SetMethodInteface(mmi : IMyMethodInterface); stdcall; external 'mydll.dll';
```

here is an DLL sample code:

```
library Project3;
// uses YourMethodIntf.pas
{$R *.res}

var AppMethod : IMyMethodInterface;

    procedure SetAppMethodCallback(mmi : IMyMethodInterface); stdcall;
    begin
        AppMethod := mmi;
    end;

    procedure AnotherDllMethod();
    begin
        //here you can use AppMethod.MyMethod();
    end;

exports
    SetAppMethodCallback name 'SetMethodcallback';

begin
end.
```

take into account that your `mmo` object (`TMyMethodInterface`) will not be destroyed until you set `AppMethod` in dll to `nil` (or FreeLibrary dll ), so be careful

Comment: I know it's much to ask but could you post me complete skeleton of such dll?

Comment: thanks a lot, I'll be looking into it from Monday, since my work hours are almost done for the week :)

Comment: @JacekKwiecień you have to declare your interface in separate pas-file and then include it into both dll and app projects.

Comment: figured it out :) what should I implement so functions LoadLibary and GetProcAddress are recognised by program?: EDIT: Figured that out too: Its Windows :)

Comment: when I'm trying to execute AppMethod.MyMethod(); it throws exception - obviously because my AppMethod is nil - how and when should I initialize it?

Comment: @JacekKwiecień I've uploaded sample project group (app + dll) to http://file.karelia.ru/zk458v/ (appCallback.zip)

Comment: thanks you helped me a lot. I've made it working. inbelieveable :)